# How to bind the kafka producer configuration to target topic/channel?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

currently I am doing the testing for kafka producer to limit the 'retries' to 2-3 times when the kafka messages failed to send out.

By now, what I understand is in Spring properties, we can setup below configuration to limit the producer retries by adding

**spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.retries=3
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.retry.backoff.ms=1000**

But as I know, this setting will make producer to retries only 3 times when failed to send out message in all topic.

May I know are we able to setup this config only apply to single topic or single channel?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties

and https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-producer-properties

For example

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.myBinding-0-in.consumer.configuration
```

> **configuration**

> Map with a key/value pair containing generic Kafka consumer properties. In addition to having Kafka consumer properties, other configuration properties can be passed here. For example some properties needed by the application such as spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.configuration.foo=bar. The bootstrap.servers property cannot be set here; use multi-binder support if you need to connect to multiple clusters.

> Default: Empty map.